# when to use direct sql query vs type-safe slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I am not sure when slick runs the sql query and returns the result set. I want to run different queries but my table is very big. The sql command it self takes few seconds to run. I am afraid if I use slick to return entire table and then do selection or group by, it consumes a lot of memory and makes everything slow.

Here is one example to get the count of customers per day:

```scala
sql"""
      select timestamp::date, count(distinct id) from tenant GROUP BY timestamp::date ORDER BY timestamp::date asc;
    """.as[(Date, Int)]
```

My table has multiple columns other than date and id. If I want to bring the entire table and then to do group by and map in scala, it takes a lot of memory.
If I use above command, it is prone to errors.

Is there a way to return only id and date from sql db? and then what is the best way to do group by?

I have tried above sql command but not sure how to use slick better.

Comment: You should probably share the different codes you tried and want to compare. I've the feeling you're misunderstanding how Slick works.

Comment: Whether you use Slick DSL for creating query or writing it with sql interpolators is unrelated to the size of data that you are fetching but what is easier to maintain in your codebase - simple CRUD queries, will be probably easier to write with the DSL which will make it easy to update after schema migration (all places where types will change will stop compiling), complex queries might be easier to write with interpolator, they would be harder to fix just by looking at code but easier to update by cop-paste-run-possibly-fix in SQL CLI. YMMV